# Error while initializing facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm following the [official login tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#step2) and suddenly I've got an error. I'm new to android so I'm a bit confused. So, here is my `FBMainFragment` like `MainFragment` in official tutorial:

```
public class FBMainFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_networks, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.FB_Login);
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(MenuActivity.TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(MenuActivity.TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

... and here is my `SocialNetworksActivity` class like `MainActivity` in off. doc.:

```
public class SocialNetworksActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private FBMainFragment fbMainFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        fbMainFragment = new FBMainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fbMainFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        fbMainFragment = (FBMainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
```

As you see, I don't finished the tutorial yet. Now I'm in the end of the 2 part. But, as it sais, *Build and run your project. Log in with Facebook. You should be taken through the permissions screen.*. So i tryed to run my project and my app just felt. Any ideas? ;)

Comment: you have to include a loginActivity of Facebook in manifest and also need to add app ID, did you do that

Comment: Yes, I've added the line `<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />` to my manifest but i don't get where should i put my ID. Maybe I'm wrong but i thing there way no word about it in the tutorial in 1 and 2 parts @PankajNimgade

Comment: Maybe I should do it all without testing and then it will be esier to you to recognize the error?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/ try this, app id is needed in manifest as well, take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added this code in manifest and everything now is working OK. @PankajNimgade, thanks for help.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/FB_AppID"/>
```

**P.S** `FB_AppID` is my facebook app id